# EvaluationContext Null With Spring Integration and Kafka

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am attempting to define a simple message flow in Spring Integration that reads from one channel and then dumps the messages into a Kafka queue. To do this, I am using [spring-integration-kafka](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-kafka). The problem is I get an `EvaluationContext` error I can't decipher.

Here is my configuration in XML:

```
<int:channel id="myStreamChannel"/>
<int:gateway id="myGateway" service-interface="com.myApp.MyGateway" >
    <int:method name="process" request-channel="myStreamChannel"/>
</int:gateway>
<int:channel id="activityOutputChannel"/>
<int:transformer input-channel="myStreamChannel" output-channel="activityOutputChannel" ref="activityTransformer"/>    
<int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter id="kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter"
                                    kafka-producer-context-ref="kafkaProducerContext"
                                    auto-startup="false"
                                    channel="activityOutputChannel"
                                    topic="my-test"
                                    message-key-expression="header.messageKey">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="1000" time-unit="MILLISECONDS" receive-timeout="0" task-executor="taskExecutor"/>
</int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter>

<task:executor id="taskExecutor"
               pool-size="5-25"
               queue-capacity="20"
               keep-alive="120"/>

<int-kafka:producer-context id="kafkaProducerContext" producer-properties="producerProperties">
    <int-kafka:producer-configurations>
        <int-kafka:producer-configuration broker-list="kafkaserver.com:9092"
                                          key-class-type="java.lang.String"
                                          value-class-type="java.lang.String"
                                          topic="my-test"
                                          key-encoder="stringEncoder"
                                          value-encoder="stringEncoder"
                                          compression-codec="snappy"/>
    </int-kafka:producer-configurations>
</int-kafka:producer-context>
```

When I run my application via Spring Boot, I get this exception:

*Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Assertion failed] - this argument is required; it must not be null*

This is the offending line in the stack trace:

*at org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler.onInit(KafkaProducerMessageHandler.java:68)*

Here is what happens at Line 68:

`Assert.notNull(this.evaluationContext);`

So the `EvaluationContext` is null. I have no idea why.

By the way, when I replace the Kafka endpoint with a trivial `stdout` endpoint to print the message body, everything works fine.

Can you tell me what is wrong with my Kafka endpoint configuration that there is no `EvaluationContext` available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue belongs to the version mismatch hell.
The Spring Boot pulls that Spring Integration Core version, which doesn't support `IntegrationEvaluationContextAware` to populate the `EvaluationContext` in the `KafkaProducerMessageHandler`.

So, you should upgrade Spring Integration Kafka to most recent release: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-kafka/releases